# Storing fibonacci in an array and printing the user desired value

Tags: java, fibonacci

I have written a code for printing the fibonacci series and i want to store it in a dynamic array.
Then later when the user inputs a value for printing a particular element of the array,it should display the value of the required fibonacci number stored in the array.

```
package fibonacci;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int size=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        int fibonacci[]=new int[size];
        int i=3;

        System.out.println("The number");

        int number=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        for(int i1=1;i1<=number;i1++){

            System.out.println(fibonacci(i1)+" ");

        }
        int j=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        System.out.println(fibonacci[i]);

    }




        public static int fibonacci(int number){
                if(number==1||number==2){
                        return 1;

                    }
                    return fibonacci(number-1)+fibonacci(number-2);

            }
    }
```

Comment: So, what is the actual question? - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could take advantage of the array and use it like this

fibonacci[i]=fibonacci[i-1]+fibonnaci[i-2] this will improve the execution of the code very much because recursive functions can have high complexity you wouldn't notice the diference in small values but with big values like fibonacci[1000] you will notice the difference you can make your cpu and memory suffer and bring them to their knees so i will give you Fibonacci1 that is your version and Fibonacci2 the easier version:

**Fibonacci1**

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Fibonacci1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out
                    .println("enter the upper bound of the serie(Size of the array of fibonacci serie):");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            int fibonacci[] = new int[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                fibonacci[i] = fibonacci(i+1);
            }

            System.out.println("enter a number between 1 and " + size);

            int j = scanner.nextInt();
            while (j < 0 || j > size) {
                if (j < 0) {
                    System.out.println("j<0");
                }
                if (j > size) {
                    System.out.println("j>" + size);
                }
                System.out.println("please enter a number between 1 and " + size);
            }

            System.out.println("Fibonacci[" + j + "]=" + fibonacci[j - 1]);
            scanner.close();
        }

        public static int fibonacci(int number) {
            if (number == 1 || number == 2) {
                return 1;
            }
            return fibonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2);

        }
    }
```

**Fibonacci2:**

package stackOverFlow;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonnaci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out
                .println("enter the upper bound of the serie(Size of the array of fibonacci serie):");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        int fibonacci[] = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            fibonacci[i] = fibonacci(i + 1, fibonacci);
        }

        System.out.println("enter a number between 1 and " + size);

        int j = scanner.nextInt();
        while (j < 0 || j > size) {
            if (j < 0) {
                System.out.println("j<0");
            }
            if (j > size) {
                System.out.println("j>" + size);
            }
            System.out.println("please enter a number between 1 and " + size);
        }
        System.out.println("Fibonacci[" + j + "]=" + fibonacci[j - 1]);
        scanner.close();
    }

    /*
     * changed the fibonacci function in order to use the already calculated
     * fibonacci elements
     * fibSerie[n]=fibonnaci[n-1]
     * fibSerie[n-1]=fibonnaci[n-2];
     * fibSerie[n-2]=fibonnaci[n-3];
     * because arrays start from 0 so fibSerie[1]=fibonnaci[0];
     */
    public static int fibonacci(int number, int[] fibonacci) {
        if (number == 1 || number == 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        return fibonacci[number - 2] + fibonacci[number - 3];

    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain why in fibonacci1 u have given fibonacci(i)=fibonacci(i+1) ?

Comment: it is mainly because arrays start the index in 0 so in fibonnaciArray[0] we store the fibonacciSerie(1) . so in general fibonacciArray[n-1] will store the fibonacciSerie(n)

Comment: Didnt exactly understand your point of view.But I'll try going through it again.Thank you

Comment: ok lets rename the array wich we use to save our fibonacci results to int[] fibArray okey

Comment: ok lets rename the array wich we use to save our fibonacci results to int[] fibArray okey and the function fibonnaci will be the equivalent of the serie fibonacci so fibonaci(n) is nth element of fibonacci serie Okey what happens is when we start saving our results that fibonacci function gives us is we store fibonacci(1) in fibArray[0], fibonacci(2) in fibArray[1] so you notice that there is gap so fibArray[n] is going to be storing  the result of fibonacci(n+1)

Comment: Good explanation sir,Thank you..i understood now.

Answer (score 2):

There is only about 94 fibonacci values which fit into a `long` so you can create these on startup.  Also using a loop to create the numbers is `O(n)`, however using recursion is equal to the answer which is exponential.  You quickly get numbers which will take longer than the age of the universe to calculate.

Comment: Sir,the question which i saw online was to solve using recursion itself

Comment: @ManojKSharma Java doesn't optimise recursion in the way some other languages do e.g. it doesn't have memorization so you have use iteration (as the accepted answer does) though using a simple loop would be much cleaner.

Comment: Yes,i agree.But the question i received was so.Thank you